# SQL SRSS create a list which changes after user input value is added

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2010, reporting-services, user-input

I am using SQL Server in Visual Studio 2010.

I set up a report which grabs a list of all IDs that start with '999' from two separate databases, and will allow the user to type in an ID to view that information. I checked my SQL query and it all works fine, but here is my issue:

I can either have the report print that entire list when the user input area is blank and you hit 'View Report', or I can set it so that the user has to input a value, and then only that value is printed as a result.

I can't seem to make it do BOTH, and I actually want this report to be able to do both! In other words, when the user leaves the input box blank, it prints the whole list (of 752 IDs), or if they type in a value that exists, it will only show that one. Is this possible in Visual Studio 2010?

**FYI**

I set up a parameter called `@ID`, and I created a dataset called 'AssignedID', and if you add this line at the end, it will print only the user input value:

```
 WHERE emp_ID = @ID
```

And then of course, without that line, it will print the whole list of 752 IDs. But, I want it to be capable of both.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you allow a NULL parameter and use (from memory)
`WHERE (emp_ID = @ID or @ID is NULL)`

Comment: I am not sure if this changed anything. When I add in that line, and set @ID = ' ', then the list still comes up blank. If I set it to an ID number that exists, then that ID will appear.

Comment: As a SQL query, I can make what you are saying work. I can add in your WHERE clause, and add this in the beginning: 

declare @ID int;
set @ID=NULL

However, this does not translate to VS reporting :/ I just get a message saying that the ID variable is already set.  How can I set the variable so that VS can understand?

Comment: You'll need to remove the "declare/set" statement and just add your code with the "where" query and Reporting Services will use the parameter. 
You just need to ensure that the parameter is set to allow NULL values.

Comment: Here's my query
`Select top 5 FirstForename, Surname, RefNo
from ProSolution.dbo.StudentDetail
where AcademicYearID = '17/18'
and StudentID IN  (@StudentID) or @StudentID is null`

The StudentID parameter is set to allow blank and allow null
Available Values set to none
Default Value entered as NULL

When you run the report, you should get a tickbox with the word NULL next to it.

Comment: Ok, I see it now. So I set the parameter to allow NULL values (I had it set to allow blank), and the Default value to be NULL. Then it worked! Thank you!